# How to get Subversion repository from svn:// and https://?

Tags: svn, redmine, visualsvn-server, svnserve

I know these are noob questions, but I never got my own Subversion running before and I'm kinda lost.

I installed VisualSVN in Windows, but it doesn't support svn:// protocol by default, only HTTP or HTTPS.

It is working fine over HTTP, and I'm able to manage it from its management tool, see its repositories and get their HTTP-based URL, and from that I'm able to use Tortoise to check out and check in. I'm able to check out from a repository URL using Tortoise: `http://Main:90/svn/HikariKrumo/`

But I need svn:// protocol for Redmine to access it. Redmine says to support http:// but it reports this error message: `The entry or revision was not found in the repository.`. And I need HTTPS to access it from Internet.

If I can get Redmine to access it from svn:// I can just configure it to use HTTPS in place of HTTP, and I hope it all to works.

I like VisualSVN because of its management tool, but I can use another Subversion distro if needed, as long as it supports svn:// and https://. I'm getting crazy on it because it should be simple but I can't get it to work.

Comment: I'm gonna try to make it simpler. I have Bitnami Redmine built-in Subversion svnserve.exe running on port 3691. I created a project `svnadmin create project1`. Now how can I get its URL and access it?

Comment: Simple: Install Cygwin and use the command-line svn client.

Comment: @DeerHunter - that's a terrible suggestion. There are svn command line clients complied for Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you [run svnserver](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-serversetup-svnserve.html) you:

- **must before creating the repository**

define a root for svnserve at the same location, where you already have SVNParentPath - read "Running svnserve" section for details.

In this case every repository created will be reacheable via http:// and svn:// at the same time